# implications of being a record owner?

Tags: force.com, ownership

what kind of logic does record ownership drive? here's what i can think of:

1. owner of the master is the owner of the detail.
2. ownership  (or lack of) drives queues
3. ownership can drive logic (workflow, validation, formula fields....)

Anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Are you asking these questions out of genuine business need or are they meant to be something like a generic guide (and perhaps even community wiki)? Have you tried digging in Help & Training? Anyway - what comes to mind is "My/My team's" in reports, listviews, sharing rules. Storage usage statistics. Available actions on related Notes & Attachments under owned record (non-Sysadmins who don't own them can't update/delete if I recall correctly). Need to have at least "Read" right to owned object (fun if people want to transfer Cases to wrong users)...

Comment: Sharing and record visibility most importantly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ownership is one of the few ways of being granted full control of a record (the other being the role hierarchy). Full control at the sharing level grants the ability to transfer ownership to other users, as well as delete the record. This applies across all standard and custom objects. There are a number of features related to ownership that are specific to standard objects as well, and vary by the object type.

Note that apex managed sharing, sharing rules, and manual shares can only grant the lesser read and edit permissions, both of which do not allow deletion or changes in ownership on the record.

Answer (score 1):

Only an Opportunity Owner can override the Forecast Category, I believe. That's a little perk of being the owner. No idea if Opportunity Team members enjoy the same privilege.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see that you're missing is that if your org is using profiles and roles, when it comes to security, only those people directly above you in the hierarchy will have the same visibility and access to your records as you do.

Unless you share with someone who's lateral to you, or unless there are other sharing groups, managers in the hierarchy that are lateral to you in the org, won't have the same access and visibility to your records as YOUR manager does; simply due to the fact that YOU'RE the owner of the record. What visibility and access the managers have to records you own will of course be dependant on the security model that was set-up for the org in general and the specific application you're using.

The [Force.com Platform Fundamentals Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf) would be a good resource to look at if you're really trying to flesh this out. Two other resources would be the [Security Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_security/workbook_security.pdf) and the [Security Developer Cheatsheet](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_security_developer_cheatsheet.pdf).

I'll add that the only places where I see ownership driving logic is primarily with workflow in that an owner's supervisor and that person's manager, etc would be the people up the chain who'd likely be the people required for approvals, but not necessarily as it would depend on the type of record and the purpose of the approval (e.g. accounting might need to approve a new account for credit while sales doesn't report to accounting). I don't really see it happening with validation unless you're implying that only the owner of a record can change it. We all know as admins that isn't entirely the case. When using hierarchies, managers can also change things too! Formula fields, okay, it looks up the owner's user Id.